# Split duplicates in lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, card

So far I have this code

```
public class Card
{
    public int suitID;
    public int cardValue;
}

public class DeckManager
{
    private List<List<Card>> FindCardsPerSuit(List<Card> cards)
    {
        var _cardsCombination = cards
                                .GroupBy(x => x.cardValue)
                                .Where(g => g.Count() > 2)
                                .Select(c => c.ToList())
                                .ToList();

        return _cardsCombination;
    }
}
```

I'm working on a Rummy card game and what I'm trying to do is to find if the combination of cards that the player want to play is valid or not.

When the player selects some cards from the hand, I need to check if the cards with the same value have a unique suit, otherwise, add it to a new list.

[image: Rummy card combination]

Example:
The player has 8 cards all with the same value but different suits, the min combination is 4 so you can do 2 combinations, and because you play with 2 decks you have 2 cards per suit.

How can I find out if I want to create a list of lists of combinations?

At the moment the _cardsCombination query gets all the cards selected and make a smaller group with all the cards with the same value. How can I do the same thing and create subgroups for each card with suit duplicate?

Thank you.

Comment: You man like using [`.Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) ?

Comment: I don't really know the game, but since you're working with permutations, or combinations as you call it, based on the cards - its usually easier to remove the combination from the hand after analysing. This way you'll be able to reapply the logic on the leftover hand.

Comment: I already tried both of these solutions but I cannot figure out how to do it. 
I just ended up with a list of {3 hearts - 3 hearts}, {3 diamonds - 3 diamonds},{3 spades - 3 spades}, {3 clubs - 3 clubs} instead of {3 hearts - 3 diamonds - 3 spades - 3 clubs},{3 hearts - 3 diamonds - 3 spades - 3 clubs}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _cardsCombination = cards
    .GroupBy(x => x.cardValue)
    .SelectMany(g => {
        // group cards by suit
        var cardsPerSuit = g.GroupBy(c => c.suitId);
            
        // max number of cards with same suit (will be 1 or 2 for two decks)
        // this will be number of subsets
        var maxCardsPerSuit = cardsPerSuit.Max(gg => gg.Count());
        
        return Enumerable
            // create subset for each setNumber from 0 to maxCardsPerSuit - 1
            .Range(0, maxCardsPerSuit)
            .Select(setNumber => cardsPerSuit
                // take nth card from each suit
                .Select(s => s.ElementAtOrDefault(setNumber))
                // skip nulls
                .Where(s => s != null)
            );
    })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 2)
    .Select(c => c.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: For some reason, I did not receive the answer notification. Thank you so much for your answer, I will try it ASAP! :)
(Meanwhile, I wrote like 60+ lines of code with nested for, to make it work)

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your time(and for the comments in the code), this works like magic to me! (I definitely need to study more LINQ)